# Can't run my code, and I don't know why it doesn't work

Tags: c

I thought it was the compiler's problem. At first, I used dev c++, and it crashes. Then, I used code blocks, but it shows nothing on the terminal. I am wondering whether it is Windows 10 problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NUM_PLANETS 9

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char *planets[] = {"Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn",
      "Uranus", "Neptune", "Pluto"};
  int i, j;
  for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < NUM_PLANETS; j++) {
      if (strcmp(argv[i], planets[j]) == 0) {
        printf("%s is planet %d\n", argv[i], j + 1);
        break;
      }
      if (j == NUM_PLANETS)
        printf("%s is not a planet.\n", argv[i]);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: With re-formatted code - it should be easy to see `if (j == NUM_PLANETS)` is never true.

Comment: Is Pluto a planet again? Better not to hardcode the number of planets, but take the number from the list of planets in case classifications change: `size_t num_planets = sizeof planets / sizeof *planets;`.

Comment: looks like you did not supply a command line parameter (that is one of the planet names)  Note: when using the command line parameters: the code should check the number of parameters and output a USAGE message to `stderr` when there is 'non'

Comment: @chux, actually, the second `for()` loop will have (when no matching planet name is found) incremented `j` to be 9, so then the last `if()` will be true.

Comment: I don't think there is something wrong with the code because it's from the book. What i mean is, when i try to use the command line options, like: argc argv, there will be problems. but i just don't know how to fix that, is that a compiler's problem? do i need to change some settings?

Comment: @user3629249 -- look at the braces again; this was chux' point about the reformatting.

Comment: @user3629249 No. `if (j == NUM_PLANETS)` is within `for (j = 0; j < NUM_PLANETS; j++) { ...}`.  `j  == NUM_PLANETS)` is never true.  OP's problem is unnecessarily more difficult to see with poorly formated code.

Comment: (egg on face) *sigh* I totally missed the incorrect location of the braces

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. checks for missing command line parameter
2. properly exits the program when there is no command line parameter
3. follows the axion: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

and now the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NUM_PLANETS 9

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
  char *planets[] = 
  {
      "Mercury", 
      "Venus", 
      "Earth", 
      "Mars", 
      "Jupiter", 
      "Saturn",
      "Uranus", 
      "Neptune", 
      "Pluto"
  };

  int i;
  int j;

  if (argc < 2 )
  {
      printf( "USAGE: %s <planet name> ...\n", argv[0] );
      exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
  }

  for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) 
  {
    for (j = 0; j < NUM_PLANETS; j++) 
    {
      if (strcmp(argv[i], planets[j]) == 0) 
      {
        printf("%s is planet %d\n", argv[i], j + 1);
        break;
      }
    }

    if (j == NUM_PLANETS)
        printf("%s is not a planet.\n", argv[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```